# How to commit docker container with shared volume content

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have created a docker image of the working environment that I use for my project.

Now I am running the docker using

```
$ docker run -it -p 80:80 -v ~/api:/api <Image ID> bash
```

I do this because I don't want to develop in command line and this way I can have my project in `api` volume and can run the project from inside too.

Now, when I commit the container to share the latest development with someone, it doesn't pack the `api` volume.

Is there any way I can commit the **shared volume** along with the container?

Or is there any better way to develop from host and continuously have it reflected inside docker then the one I am using (shared volume)?

Answer (score 1):

A way to go is following:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM something
...
COPY .api/:/api
...
```

Then build:

```
docker build . -t myapi
```

Then run:

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 -v ~/api:/api myapi bash
```

At this point you have `myapi` image with the first state (when you copied with COPY), and at runtime the container has /api overrided by the directory binding.

Then to share your image to someone, just build again, so you will get a new and updated `myapi` ready to be shared.